# How to make Div Visible of Aspx page, After a Radwindow pops Up

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0

How to make Div Visible of Aspx page, After a Radwindow pops Up.. So that it looks like the light Box.

I have embedded silver light Component in aspx page . And in silverlight Component there are images in thumbnail size . when , I click on the thumbnail the radwindow opens with the original image and in big size.  After Pops up , Only the area under the silverlight Component get gray Color.

I need Whole window should have gary background color  , So it look s like Light box.

So , I need to call Div after rad Window pops up.

Please Visit: I have Shared 2 files.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5yo_3I2aEWcbWFGb3FKWURZLVU/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5yo_3I2aEWcZThfcUxUb3JUTHM/edit?usp=sharing